# Return Modal Average in LINQ (Mode)

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am not sure if CopyMost is the correct term to use here, but it's the term my client used ("CopyMost Data Protocol"). Sounds like he wants the mode? I have a set of data:

```
Increment    Value
.02            1
.04            1
.06            1
.08            2
.10            2
```

I need to return which Value occurs the most "CopyMost". In this case, the value is 1. Right now I had planned on writing an Extension Method for IEnumerable to do this for integer values. Is there something built into Linq that already does this easily? Or is it best for me to write an extension method that would look something like this

```
records.CopyMost(x => x.Value);
```

**EDIT**

Looks like I am looking for the modal average. I've provided an updated answer that allows for a tiebreaker condition. It's meant to be used like this, and is generic.

```
records.CopyMost(x => x.Value, x => x == 0);
```

In this case x.Value would be an int, and if the the count of 0s was the same as the counts of 1s and 3s, it would tiebreak on 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's one option:

```
var query = (from item in data
             group 1 by item.Value into g
             orderby g.Count() descending
             select g.Key).First();
```

Basically we're using `GroupBy` to group by the value - but all we're interested in for each group is the *size* of the group and the *key* (which is the original value). We sort the groups by size, and take the first element (the one with the most elements).

Does that help?

Comment: It all makes sense, except the 1. "group 1 by item.Value into g". Why 1? Why not item? I tested and they both yield the same result. I know the 1 is probably better for some reason, but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: @jsmith: Just to indicate that you really don't care about the values within the group. You might even use `(byte) 1` to be more efficient :)

Comment: So what happens if I were to use a different value, say `group 2`?

Comment: @msarchet: Nothing would change. We don't care about the values in the group, only the group's size. They could be goldfish for all the difference it'll make to the results.

Answer (score 2):

Jon beat me to it, but the term you're looking for is [Modal Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).

**Edit:**

If I'm right In thinking that it's modal average you need then the following should do the trick:

```
var i = (from t in data
         group t by t.Value into aggr
         orderby aggr.Count() descending
         select aggr.Key).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

This method has been updated several times in my code over the years. It's become a very important method, and is much different than it use to be. I wanted to provide the most up to date version in case anyone was looking to add CopyMost or a Modal Average as a linq extension.

One thing I did not think I would need was a tiebreaker of some sort. I have now overloaded the method to include a tiebreaker.

```
public static K CopyMost<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> records, Func<T, K> propertySelector, Func<K, bool> tieBreaker)
{
    var grouped = records.GroupBy(x => propertySelector(x)).Select(x => new { Group = x, Count = x.Count() });
    var maxCount = grouped.Max(x => x.Count);
    var subGroup = grouped.Where(x => x.Count == maxCount);

    if (subGroup.Count() == 1)
        return subGroup.Single().Group.Key;
    else
        return subGroup.Where(x => tieBreaker(x.Group.Key)).Single().Group.Key;
}
```

The above assumes the user enters a legitimate tiebreaker condition. You may want to check and see if the tiebreaker returns a valid value, and if not, throw an exception. And here's my normal method.

```
public static K CopyMost<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> records, Func<T, K> propertySelector)
{
    return records.GroupBy(x => propertySelector(x)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Key).First();
}
```